# how to insert the tamil letter in properties(for example Config.ppt)

Tags: java, unicode, properties-file, tamil

how to insert the tamil letter in properties(for example Config.ppt)
 i need to write the Tamil letter in a Properties file

```
  fieldvalue = fieldvalue.replace(specialcharArray.get(g),  specialcharArray1.get(g));
  // specialcharArray.get(g) and specialcharArray1.get(g) are given in the Config.ppt file.


 for (int g = 0; g < specialcharArray.size(); g++) {
            if (g < specialcharArray1.size()) {
                fieldvalue = fieldvalue.replace(specialcharArray.get(g), specialcharArray1.get(g));
            } else {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Find and replace characters count mismatching. Please Re-run the application after making the count equal otherwise none of the characters will be replaced");
                System.exit(0);
            }
```

Comment: I don't see what the code has to do with the question

Comment: How to insert the tamil letter in properties(for example Config.ppt) this is my question.then use that tamil letter for Find and Replace.

Comment: Create your properties file using UTF-8 encoding, create an `InputStreamReader` with UTF-8 encoding and pass to  `java.util.Properties`.

Comment: Can you try with UTF -8 encoding means it will solve.

Comment: Please Explain it in brief